# AppLocker Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, security

Windows 8 only includes AppLocker support in the Enterprise version (Where as Ultimate and Enterprise had it in Win7) it's there in Win8 Pro but doesn't enforce the rules.

SRP runs in usermode and doesn't allow exceptions so it's off the cards.

And volume licensing is 5+ from what I can see...

Is there a way I can get Applocker without having to spend a huge amount? I only need one license.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch on enforcement, I guess this works on Pro as well: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh994579.aspx

Answer (score 0):

James:  I am actually in the same boat - I would like to use AppLocker, and am willing to purchase an "Ultimate" type version for AppLocker support, but am out of luck since it is only available to Enterprise users.  And as you pointed out, purchasing 5 licenses for one computer is just not worth it.  Here are some links regarding this that confirm this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/14cb0b1e-20e9-4c10-9061-3b77a96b23cf

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/W8ITProPreRel/thread/d4609974-0a79-4710-b6e8-0ac6b055f620

However, regarding SRP, can you clarify what you mean by "SRP runs in usermode and doesn't allow exceptions so it's off the cards"?  I have set up SRP and have successfully set up exceptions for non admin users.